# First response after refresh page from axios is empty

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, react-hooks, axios

This function is called up after pressing the button. Whenever the page is refreshed and the button is pressed, it is empty, the second click returns an array with correct data

```
  const loginUser = (e) => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/user/Allusers',{
    }).then(response => {
      setUserArray(response.data)
      console.log(userExists(LoginUsername,LoginPassword)); //Check if user exist in UserArray
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log(error);
    });
  
}
```

Can someone explain why array is empty on the first click? And how could I improve it

Comment: Can you share some more code or a reproducible sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Because `setUserArray(response.data)` is asynchronous.and `userExists(LoginUsername,LoginPassword)` runs before.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: I tried something like that: setUserArray(function() {return response.data;})  or array function and function still work same way. On first click i get empty array.

Comment: you can pass the array to userExists to as an argument userExists(LoginUsername,LoginPassword, response.data)

Comment: Working properly, perfect answer